# How to set a Threshold for Imgproc.matchTemplate opencv android?

Tags: android, opencv

```
    int match_method = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;

    int result_cols = labReport.cols() - textMat.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = labReport.rows() - textMat.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    Imgproc.matchTemplate(labReport, textMat, result, match_method);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

    Point matchLoc;
    if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF
            || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
        matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    } else {
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    }

    return matchLoc;
```

I'm using this code. I am trying to find a template in my image, however if I use a template that I know is not in the image, `Imgproc.matchTemplate`, it will return me a point as a result.

I need something like threshold for this. I need similarity more than 80% and if it's not, then return me some value like `null`.